# Does infinitely many functions f(n) satisfy Θ(g(n))?

Tags: asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

In the context of asymptotic notation, are there infinitely many functions $f(n)$ that is a member of $\Theta( g(n) )$?

---

**My thoughts**

Let's say we set f(n) to be equal to a constant.

We would then always be able to increase either $c_1$ or $c_2$ to be able to create more $f(n)$.

So in the case of constants, *I believe* that infinitely many $f(n)$ is a member of $\Theta(g(n))$.

Now the question is, does this hold true for other higher order functions? I am not sure..

Comment: $g(n)$ is obviously $\Theta(g(n))$.  Now construct an $f$ by finding some $h(n)$ that is $\Theta(g(n)/n)$: $f(n)=g(n)+h(n)$.  This is also, then, $\Theta(g(n))$.  But infinitely many $f(n)$ can be constructed in this way by multiplying $h(n)$ by any constant you want: $f(n)\rightarrow f(n)+C h(n)$.  So there are infinitely many functions satisfying $\Theta(g(n))$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, infinitely many functions $f(n)$ are $\Theta(g(n))$.  For any $g(n)$, the functions given by
$$
f(n) = C g(n),
$$
where $C > 0$ is a constant, form an infinite family of functions that are $\Theta(g(n))$.

Comment: I suppose there are infinitely many functions that are a member of Ω(g(n)) and O(g(n)) too then, right? I mean, the same principle should apply..

Comment: Yes, that's right